# perform normalisation on pairs of columns

Tags: r, dplyr, normalization

I have a large dataframe:

```
df <- data.frame(S.1_Dxx = runif(100, min = 1, max = 3.5)
                 ,S.1_Px1 = runif(100, min = 0.5, max = 3)
                 ,S.2_Dxhfah = runif(100, min = 0.7, max = 2)
                 ,S.2_Pxhgm = runif(100, min = 0.4, max = 1.4)
                 ,S._Dxhgm = runif(100, min = 1, max = 2.5)
                 ,S._Pxhgm = runif(100, min = 0.4, max = 1.4)
)
```

The beginning of the column name always starts with `S.`, then has 0-6 numbers followed by `_`. This prefix (from `S` to `_`) uniquely identifies pairs of columns that I would like to normalise.

I can do it manually:

```
library(limma)

normS1 <- df %>% 
  select(starts_with("S.1_")) %>%
  as.matrix() %>% 
  normalizeBetweenArrays(method = "scale") %>% 
  as.data.frame()
```

However, I would like to perform this normalisation for all column pairs.

I imagine the beginning would like like this:

```
multiNormDf <- df %>% 
  pivot_longer(everything(), names_to = "sample", values_to = "intensity") %>% 
  mutate(sampleGroup = word(sample, start = 1, sep = "_")) %>% 
  group_by(sampleGroup)
```

And this is where I get stuck. How to ensure that within `sampleGroup` the two `samples` are seen as separate samples? Maybe I should instead slice the `Df` into smaller dataframes, perform this operation on each and then bind them back?

Also, I appreciate that normalising pairs of columns, rather than the whole dataset, is rarely a good idea. In this case, however, this seems the best course of action.

EDIT: I changed the type of normalisation (from `vsn` to `normalizeBeteweenArrays`, which probably more poeple are familiar with)

Comment: I'm not too familiar with `justvsn` but it seems to require a reference and and experimental. Does the ending of the column name indicate which is which?

Comment: The ending of the column is different for each column. I will edit the question to remove vsn from it - it can be any other normalisation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below is one approach using {dplyover} which should work in theory. Disclaimer: I'm the maintainer of {dplyover} which is not on CRAN.

We can use `over()` to loop over an object, here a string created with `cut_names()` which gets the first part of your variable names. We use this string as `.x` in `across(starts_with(paste0(.x, "_")` and this is your `data.frame` that you can now pipe into `as.matrix()` and then into `justvsn()`. Depending on the output we might need to wrap the result in `list()`. Maybe you don't need to `as.data.frame()` this depends on what `justvsn()` returns.

The columns names will be the strings from `.x` but we can adjust the names easily with `over()`'s `.names` argument.

```r
df <- data.frame(S.1_Dxx = runif(100, min = 1, max = 3.5)
                 ,S.1_Px1 = runif(100, min = 0.5, max = 3)
                 ,S.2_Dxhfah = runif(100, min = 0.7, max = 2)
                 ,S.2_Pxhgm = runif(100, min = 0.4, max = 1.4)
                 ,S._Dxhgm = runif(100, min = 1, max = 2.5)
                 ,S._Pxhgm = runif(100, min = 0.4, max = 1.4)
)


library(dplyr)
library(dplyover)
library(limma)

normS1 <- df %>% 
  select(starts_with("S.1_")) %>%
  as.matrix() %>% 
  normalizeBetweenArrays(method = "scale") %>% 
  as.data.frame()

df %>% 
  summarise(over(cut_names("_.*", .vars = names(df)),
                 ~ across(starts_with(paste0(.x, "_"))) %>% 
                   as.matrix() %>% 
                   normalizeBetweenArrays(method = "scale") %>% 
                   as.data.frame() 
                 )) %>% 
  do.call("data.frame", .) %>% 
  as_tibble()#  for printing

#> # A tibble: 100 x 6
#>    S.1.S.1_Dxx S.1.S.1_Px1 S.2.S.2_Dxhfah S.2.S.2_Pxhgm S..S._Dxhgm S..S._Pxhgm
#>          <dbl>       <dbl>          <dbl>         <dbl>       <dbl>       <dbl>
#>  1       1.11         1.10          1.14          0.502       1.72        1.88 
#>  2       2.75         2.00          0.853         0.758       0.844       1.15 
#>  3       2.40         1.30          0.594         1.28        1.73        1.04 
#>  4       1.28         3.43          1.05          1.32        1.13        0.677
#>  5       1.90         2.92          1.50          1.49        1.33        0.597
#>  6       3.00         2.06          0.857         0.687       0.961       1.21 
#>  7       0.919        3.35          1.43          1.25        0.792       1.81 
#>  8       2.90         1.36          1.29          1.56        1.74        1.52 
#>  9       2.95         1.36          0.832         1.36        1.41        1.44 
#> 10       1.88         2.69          1.18          1.44        0.896       0.604
#> # ... with 90 more rows
```

<sup>Created on 2022-11-09 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: TimTeaFan, I edited the question to employ a more known method of normalisation, but I think your solution will work with minor tweaks - thank you for pointing me to ```over```!

Comment: @Wera see my update with the limma package.

Comment: thank you this is perfect! Slightly related, and it feels I shouldn't ask a new question, because the answer will be similar, but I can't figure it out.  If I want to ```mutate()``` each of two-column dataframes created from ```df``` by ```over()``` to make a column ```ratio``` - dividing one column by the other, how do I do it? The numerator column has ```ddd``` string in the column name and the denominator - ```xxx```.  So I want to ```.x[contains("ddd")] / .x[contains("xxx")]``` (this code doesn't work, but something like this!).